# What are the consequences of not setting "cache-control" in http response header?

Tags: http, cache-control, http-caching

Say, my web application responds to a http request with a response that has no "cache-control" in its header. If the client-end submits the same request within a relatively short time, what would happen? Does a cached copy of the response get used and thus the request does not need to reach the server? Or does the request get sent to the server just like the first time?

If the answer is "it depends", please indicate what the dependencies are. Thanks.

Comment: What part of the explanation in RFC 2616 are you struggling with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no caching behavior defined in HTTP/1.1 protocol for a resource served with no cache-related headers, so it's really up to the HTTP client's implementation.

Here is the link to [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html).